# Does a single electron moving at velocity $v$ have an associated magnetic field, ignoring intrinsic spin?

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity

I have seen explanations of the magnetic field due to an electric current as being due to a Lorentz contraction of the moving electric charges. Would this explanation work for a single electron. There is still a current associated with a single moving electron.

Comment: You should use Google more often. Many [links](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=magnetic+field+of+moving+point+charge&oq=magnetic+field+of+moving+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.9280j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) explaining exactly your question

Comment: I understand that a single moving electron can be visualised as a current and you calculate the magnetic field due to this current using Biot Savart Law. But I was looking for an explanation using relativity and I wonder how this would work for a single electron

Comment: Sorry about that, your question heading was quite confusing. You should edit your heading to be more specific about the relativity question.

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen explanations of the magnetic field due to an electric
>   current as being due to a Lorentz contraction of the moving electric
>   charges.

I'm afraid that's not quite the correct understanding.  The magnetic field, due to an electric current, is due to the moving electric charges, *period*.

What we need to do here is be careful to distinguish between magnetic *field* and magnetic *force*.

(1) If a charged particle is *at rest* in a non-zero magnetic *field*, there will be *no* magnetic *force* on the particle.

To emphasize, only if the charged particle is *moving* in a non-zero magnetic *field* will there be a magnetic *force* acting on the particle.

I think where you've picked up the idea in the above quote is in the explanation for the *force* on a charged test particle moving with respect to a current carrying wire.

In the rest frame of the wire, the wire is uncharged and thus, the *force* on the charged particle is entirely magnetic (due to the magnetic *field* of the current).

However, *in the rest frame of the test particle*, by (1) there can be no magnetic *force* acting.

Thus the force on the particle, in this frame, must be entirely *electric* and this implies that, in this frame, the current carrying wire has a net electric charge density.

How does this charge density appear in this frame?  The fixed charge density and moving charge density (the current) in the wire are changed, due to Lorentz contraction, in this frame from their values in the rest frame of the wire.

---

So, your question is based on, I think, a misunderstanding.  A moving electric charge has an associated magnetic *field* since electric current *is* charge in motion.

To think of this in terms of relativity, simply recognize that the electric scalar potential and magnetic vector potential are components of a four-vector, the [four-potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential), and thus the components *mix together* under a Lorentz transformation.

So, a four-potential that is purely electric in character in one frame, will, in general, be both electric and magnetic in nature in other, relatively moving frames.

Comment: thanks you for this explanation, this is obviously a subject that requires careful definition of terms, which reference frame you are referring to etc

Answer (score 0):

The electromagnetic field created by a moving relativistic charged point particle is given by the [Liénard-Wiechert potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential). They are slightly more complicated than this answer really gives room for but they are essentially the solutions for the Maxwell equations in terms of potentials,
$$\partial_\mu\partial^\mu A_\nu=-\mu_0 J_\nu,$$
where you take the current density four-vector corresponding to a single particle. Thus if in a given inertial frame the particle's trajectory is characterized by $r(\tau)=(t(\tau),x_j(\tau))$, the four-current density is given by 
$$J_\nu(x)=ec\int\mathrm{d}\tau \frac{\mathrm d r_\nu}{\mathrm d\tau}\delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau))
$$
(cf. Jackson, section 14.1). One standard approach to this is to solve the problem via Green functions, and therefore first solve the fundamental equation
$$\partial_\mu\partial^\mu D(x,x')=\delta^{(4)}(x-x').$$
(This is physically very weird: it represents the scalar field of a charged particle that only exists at one point in space and at *one instant in time*. The solution is essentially a Coulomb field in the fictional particle's rest frame, propagated along the particle's forward ([or backward?](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node51.html)) light cone; see Jackson, section 12.11.) You then convolute this with the source to get
$$A_\nu(x)=-\mu_0\int\mathrm d^4 x'D(x,x')J_\nu(x')=-\mu_0ec\int\mathrm d\tau D(x,x')  \frac{\mathrm d r_\nu}{\mathrm d\tau}.$$

This solution winds up depending heavily on the concept of [retarded time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_time): given a point $x$, the retarded time $\tau_\mathrm{ret}(x)$ is the (unique) time $\tau$ such that $x$ is in the forward light cone of $r(\tau_\mathrm{ret}(x))$ - and thus the point in the trajectory $r(\tau)$ which will radiate to $x$. While this is fine, it gets *very* messy when you want to get the electric and magnetic fields, as you need to differentiate $\frac\partial{\partial x^\mu}\tau_\mathrm{ret}(x)$, and that is a pretty painful experience.

If you have specific questions, or this seems much too complicated, I'm happy to elaborate or simplify.

Comment: thanks very much for taking the time to answer so fully. It is unfortunatly complicated but that is probably because it is complicated. It does give me pointers to look into it further. The explanations for the magnetic field of a current in a wire referred to the large number of electrons in the current and even though v_driff velocity << c they produced a magnetic field through a lorentz contraction. I wondered how this argument would alter as you reduced the number of electrons to one.

Comment: The essential answer to that is either "quite a bit" in the case of a relativistic electron (as you can see), or "not too much" in the case of a slow electron: there the above reduces to its nonrelativistic limit which is essentially the Biot-Savart law for a segment of current. However, in the latter case the magnetic field is very weak and all interactions are dominated by the electrostatic Coulomb field.