# What's the equation for the magnetic field created by a single moving electron?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electrons, velocity

Suppose we have an electron moving in a straight line with velocity $v$. My question is: What is the equation that describes the magnetic field generated by this movement. I'm unsure how to proceed since Maxwells equations are in  implicit form.

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71862/does-a-single-electron-moving-at-velocity-v-have-an-associated-magnetic-field

Comment: no no  it is not duplicate ,my question is i need implicit equation for magnetic field

Comment: Sorry, so try this http://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0601/0601028.pdf

Comment: In special relativity the following is often used $\beta = \frac v c $